# Batch Script to Rename Files

Tags: vbscript, batch-file

I have looked thoroughly to find a script that can do this, as I know the question has already been asked...but I understand very little about programming.  I have 66 Folders, each containing 6 files that end in _0,_1,..._5.  An example file name is DSC_7789 Panorama_cube_0.  I need a script that I can run on each folder to replace _0 with _f, _1 with _r, _2 with _b, _3 with _l, _4 with _u, and _5 with _d.  So DSC_7789 Panorama_cube_0 would then be changed to DSC_7789 Panorama_cube_f.  I've actually done all of this myself once...it took an entire day.  Could anyone possibly point me in the write direction?  I'm assuming this would run in visual basic.  Thanks!

Comment: It isn't a script ... but AntRenamer will take care of this very well.

http://portableapps.com/apps/utilities/ant_renamer_portable

Comment: [BulkRename](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php) is an other app which can do this. +1 for renaming files an entire day...

Comment: @ marapet -- ha ha, your +1.  I second that.

Comment: WAIT A MINUTE ... a whole day to rename 396 files?  I'm thinking 1-2 hours ... o well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The REN command is very limited, but in your case it is all that is needed.

To rename the files in the current directory:

```
ren *_0 *_f
ren *_1 *_r
ren *_2 *_b
ren *_3 *_l
ren *_4 *_u
ren *_5 *_d
```

To rename all files in the current directory and all its subfolders (recursive):

```
for /d /r %%F in (.) do (
  ren "%%~fF\*_0" *_f
  ren "%%~fF\*_1" *_r
  ren "%%~fF\*_2" *_b
  ren "%%~fF\*_3" *_l
  ren "%%~fF\*_4" *_u
  ren "%%~fF\*_5" *_d
)
```

To rename all files rooted in a specific folder:

```
for /d /r "c:\your\root\here" %%F in (.) do (
  ren "%%~fF\*_0" *_f
  ren "%%~fF\*_1" *_r
  ren "%%~fF\*_2" *_b
  ren "%%~fF\*_3" *_l
  ren "%%~fF\*_4" *_u
  ren "%%~fF\*_5" *_d
)
```

**EDIT**

For anyone interested, I have finally discovered and documented the rules for how Windows RENAME handles wildcards. See [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874/109090). I had originally posted the Q&A on StackOverflow, but it was migrated to SuperUser.

Comment: +1, but, to be honest, it's a mystery to me why `ren *_0 *_f` works. I'd expect it to rename files with names like `name_0` as `name_0_f`, and yet it produces `name_f`. Strange...

Comment: @AndriyM - Yeah, I only have a rough sense of what might work. But it's still a lot of trial and error. Some day I hope to muster the fortitude to experiment and fully document how in hell the RENAME command handles wild cards. I've seen documentation for the old DOS 8.3 format, but nothing definitive for Windows with long file name support.

Comment: @AndriyM - I finally discovered the RENAME wildcard rules. See the link in the updated answer :-)